# Disable usb keyboard during suspend

Tags: linux, arch-linux, usb

I want to disable an external usb keyboard whenever the computer is put into suspend mode so that the computer can't be woken by press on the usb keyboard.

I was referred to [this site](http://r3dux.org/2014/10/how-to-fix-usb-keyboards-missing-the-first-keypress-in-linux/), but I don't see how I can make it work in my situation. I also found [this (half way down there is a script)](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1387363.html) that can run each time you suspend or wake up, but I don't know what command to issue to disable/enable keyboard

lsusb provides me with the following info about the keyboard

```
Bus 002 Device 019: ID abcd:wxyz Manufacturer Inc.
```

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be several answers for this on our sister site *askubuntu.com* such as [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/308740/421483) which asks you to

```
grep enabled /proc/acpi/wakeup
```

You should find entries for your motherboard's usb hubs such as

```
EHC1      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1d.0
EHC2      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1a.0
```

For each hub, you can toggle the setting to `disabled` by echoing into the same file just the name in the first column, eg as root

```
echo EHC1 >/proc/acpi/wakeup
```

You would need to do this after each boot of course.

If you want to understand which device is what, you can run `lspci`. Also, on some modern computers, the hub USB is `XHC` and might disable, internal/external keyboard and touchpad/mouses, all at the same time.

Comment: `You would need to do this after each boot of course.`  - if that's true that this surely cannot be a response.  I might not know Linux well enough but I doubt that that this system designers would not predict persistent settings for wakeup devices.